# Refactoring from react-native to reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We are refactoring some legacy code into React and it turns out it is all reactNative.

Does anyone have any idea how we can refactor this `AppRegistry.registerComponent` into React (Just regular React (like the one create-react-app installs), not React Native, not React-Web), the same goes for `AppRegistry.getApplication`? We don't want ANY react-native at all, so any help would be greatly appreciated...

Could someone also point me at a decent resource so I can stop asking these asinine questions? :(

Comment: By ReactJS you mean react for web?

Comment: Hi Youzef, Just regular React (like the one create-react-app installs), not React Native, not React-Web ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not need `AppRegistry` in your case. This is the [entry point](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appregistry) for your app in react native.

> AppRegistry is the JS entry point to running all React Native apps.
> App root components should register themselves with
> AppRegistry.registerComponent, then the native system can load the
> bundle for the app and then actually run the app when it's ready by
> invoking AppRegistry.runApplication.

In your app, you should refactor

```
// react native app
import App from "./App";
...
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

to

```
// your new app
import App from './App';
...
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thank you for justifying my suspicions :) I thought that was the case, but it felt too easy... Guess I might know something after all :)

You are right as well, we want to refactor out AppRegistry altogether, as it's all that's left over from React-Native/React-Native-Web, and we want to remove it...

Thank you Youzef, you're a legend ;)

Comment: How does this work for `runApplication` and `getApplication` though, the same way?

Comment: These are methods of AppRegistry and won't be required in your app